# Heavy machinery/loader attachment with custom tube

Tags: civil-engineering, mechanical

I spotted this heavy machinery/loader attachment at a road reconstruction job site in Ontario:

---

[image]

[image]

---

- The device a has horizontal tube that is cut off at an angle.
- The tube is attached to a vertical mounting plate.
- The tube portion appears to be custom built -- the angled cut through the tube is too rough to be a factory made.

---

Question:

What is the purpose of this device?

Comment: that's not a hydraulic cylinder.

Comment: ask at the site ... it does look custom made ... custom purpose probably

Comment: Could be useful in a swampy area, especially excavation in debris and mud-clogged culvert near the outlet, for which the normal excavator access is restricted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it's being used to backfill narrow watermain trenches with gravel.

[image]

---

**Edit:**

It's also used for filling up an excavator bucket with gravel -- so that the excavator doesn't need to move out of position to go over to the gravel pile.

[image]

It's hard to tell from the photo, but the excavator in the back is straddling a narrow trench. And the gravel pile is too far away for it to reach.

It seems like it would be an ordeal for the excavator to move away from its position over the trench every time it needed gravel. And in this particular location, there's not enough room for the loader to drive up and dump gravel directly into the trench.

Comment: I was three minutes too late.  There is a required depth of gravel above and below the pipe before backfilling with dirt. It can get expensive real fast if you aren't  good at placing the exact amount of gravel spec'ed for the job.

Comment: @philsweet would you mind elaborating on why does it get expensive?

Comment: Because you have to buy the gravel, and probably load and haul excess dirt away. Too little and you get fined or don't get paid. Too much and you loose money.

Answer (score 0):

They may be unrelated parts.

The top part looks like a column and baseplate that was later cannibalized and part of it was cut off to be used in a different assembly, say a 90-degree elbow.

The lower photo looks like an attachment for a small excavation machine.

Comment: the pictures are different sides of the same part?

Comment: Given the answer showing it in use, the speculation that it was two separate items is false.